# Pass Generator: How to make each password use a new line?

Tags: c++

I coded a small console application that is basically generating passwords.
It's asking the user how many passwords he want and how many characters each password should be.
It's saving the passwords to a file and it's meant to put each password on a different line.
Currently it's asking the user for characters length/amount of passwords, but it is putting it all on one line.

How would I make it so each password has it's own line?

```
string characters = "abcdefghi9182345$??=%(&)(%jklmnopqrstuv211935960473/=?$$=)&/$%=()wxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!$%&/()=";

int length;
int pwds;
int usrInpt;
int num;
```

(i know that i used some letters/numbers twice in the string above, but i did that so it uses characters like "$/(%)§" more often)

```
        cin >> usrInpt;

        if (usrInpt == 1)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << "You chose to generate a password!" << endl;
            cout << "How many passwords ?" << endl;
            cin >> pwds;
            cout << "How many characters ?" << endl;
            cin >> length;

            ofstream out_file;

            out_file.open("Passwords.txt");

            srand(time(0));
            for (int i = 0; i < pwds; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
                {
                    num = rand() % 70 + 1;

                    out_file << characters[num];

                    system("cls");

                    cout << "Passwords.txt created!" << endl;
                }
            }
```

As I said, expected is that each password gets printed out on it's own line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `out_file << std::endl;` after the second loop and before ending the first loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < pwds; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
        }
    .... 
    out_file << std::endl;
    }
```

And you also want to move the "created" message outside of the inner loop as well.

Comment: Thank you. I honestly don't know why I wasn't able to figure that out, lol!